# Skype installation on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, skype

I tried to install Skype - yes, I've read what the Debian wiki says about it, but unfortunately convincing every "friend" (like i have any, lol), family member and colleague to get on the 'alternatives' is not viable at the moment.

So, I've run the following lines as suggested:

```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
    sudo aptitude update
    sudo aptitude install libc6:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxss1:i386 libxv1:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
```

The result was quite horrifying:

```
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseaudio : Depends: libpulse0 (= 5.0-13) but 7.1-2~bpo8+1 is to be installed.
 libssl1.0.0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) which is a virtual package.
 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 : Depends: libpulse0 (= 5.0-13) but 7.1-2~bpo8+1 is to be installed.
 pulseaudio-module-x11 : Depends: libpulse0 (= 5.0-13) but 7.1-2~bpo8+1 is to be installed.
 pulseaudio-utils : Depends: libpulse0 (= 5.0-13) but 7.1-2~bpo8+1 is to be installed.
 libpulsedsp : Depends: libpulse0 (= 5.0-13) but 7.1-2~bpo8+1 is to be installed.
 libpulse0:i386 : Depends: libasyncns0:i386 (>= 0.3) which is a virtual package.
                  Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) which is a virtual package.
                  Depends: libcap2:i386 (>= 1:2.10) which is a virtual package.
                  Depends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.1.1) which is a virtual package.
                  Depends: libice6:i386 (>= 1:1.0.0) which is a virtual package.
                  Depends: libjson-c2:i386 (>= 0.10) which is a virtual package.
                  Depends: libsm6:i386 which is a virtual package.
                  Depends: libsndfile1:i386 (>= 1.0.20) which is a virtual package.
                  Depends: libsystemd0:i386 which is a virtual package.
                  Depends: libwrap0:i386 (>= 7.6-4~) which is a virtual package.
                  Depends: libx11-6:i386 which is a virtual package.
                  Depends: libx11-xcb1:i386 which is a virtual package.
                  Depends: libxcb1:i386 which is a virtual package.
                  Depends: libxtst6:i386 which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:                                                                                              
1)      empathy                                                                                                                   
2)      gdm3                                                                                                                      
3)      gnome                                                                                                                     
4)      gnome-control-center                                                                                                      
5)      gnome-core                                                                                                                
6)      gnome-music                                                                                                               
7)      gnome-packagekit                                                                                                          
8)      gnome-packagekit-session                                                                                                  
9)      gnome-session                                                                                                             
10)     gnome-settings-daemon                                                                                                     
11)     gnome-shell                                                                                                               
12)     gnome-shell-extension-weather                                                                                             
13)     gnome-shell-extensions                                                                                                    
14)     libcanberra-pulse                                                                                                         
15)     libpulse-mainloop-glib0                                                                                                   
16)     libpulsedsp                                                                                                               
17)     libspice-client-glib-2.0-8                                                                                                
18)     libspice-client-gtk-3.0-4                                                                                                 
19)     pulseaudio                                                                                                                
20)     pulseaudio-module-x11                                                                                                     
21)     pulseaudio-utils                                                                                                          
22)     task-gnome-desktop                                                                                                        
23)     vinagre                                                                                                                   

      Keep the following packages at their current version:                                                                       
24)     libpulse0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                                            
25)     libssl1.0.0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                                          

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                                                                                
26)     speech-dispatcher recommends pulseaudio                                                                                   
27)     gnome-settings-daemon recommends pulseaudio                                                                               
28)     mutter recommends gnome-session | x-session-manager                                                                       
29)     metacity recommends gnome-session | x-session-manager                                                                     
30)     gnome-online-accounts recommends gnome-control-center (>= 3.6.1)                                                          
31)     gnome-shell recommends gdm3 (>= 3.10.0.1-3~)                                                                              
32)     mousetweaks recommends gnome-control-center                                                                               
33)     gnome-control-center-data recommends gnome-control-center (>= 1:3.14.2-3)                                                 
34)     gnome-bluetooth recommends gnome-control-center                                                                           
35)     gnome-media recommends pulseaudio                                                                                         
36)     gnome-media recommends gnome-control-center                                                                               
37)     task-desktop recommends task-gnome-desktop | task-xfce-desktop | task-kde-desktop | task-lxde-desktop | task-cinnamon-desk
38)     totem-plugins recommends gnome-settings-daemon      ``
```

Needless to say, Skype installation fails and

sudo apt-get -f install

suggests removing Skype as the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm basically having the same problems on Xubuntu 15.10, which is apparently based off jessie.

I was going to suggest you just use the "dynamic" package off Skype's linux download page, but I can't get that to work either.

Bastards.

So a big part of the problem is that Skype is only shipping 32 bit binaries, and it doesn't look like all the libraries Skype has dynamically linked to ship with it.

One thing you can try is to download the dynamic package and unwrap it. Then run the skype binary from the CLI and you'll get things like

```
$./skype
./skype: error while loading shared libraries: libXv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then go digging around until you find what package that library is in, and find the i386 version of it.

It is kinda dickish of Skype/Microsoft not to keep up with things. It wouldn't take much in the way of resources.

Found this: https://github.com/haskellcamargo/skype-unofficial-client. Going to try that.

Edited to add: 
That skype-unofficial-client is some sort of wrapper around "Skype for the web".

No one who will talk to me is currently awake and online, so I'll have to give it a go tomorrow.